# Linq update many-many relationship

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

New to Linq to Entities. I am using entity framework and linq. In my db I have something akin to Cars, Users, UserCars where UserCars holds the ID from User and Cars. Standard stuff.

EF maps this to Car and User objects.

Now a user currently has many cars. Through my application I end up with a new List of Car IDs.

I need to update the UserCars table with the new list of cars for the current user.

So what needs to happen basically, The current cars for the user are deleted, and the new list of car ids/userid is inserted.

What is the easiest way to go about this using linq to entities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `User` entity should have a `Cars` property. You can just clear that collection and then add the new Cars to reflect the new state, i.e. somewhat like this:

```
User myUser = context.Users.First();
var carCollection = context.Cars.Where( c => carIdCollection.Contains(c.Id));
myUser.Cars.Clear();

foreach(Car car in carCollection)
   myUser.Cars.Add(car);

...
context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: thanks just couldn't get my.head around where to being. Should work perfect

Answer (score 0):

You could use a generic method which can handle what ever type you pass it:

```
Protected Sub UpdateManyToMany(Of T As Class)(database as SomeEntities, collection As ICollection(Of T), idList As List(Of Integer))
'update a many to many collection given a list of key IDs
  collection.Clear()
  Dim source = database.Set(Of T)()

  If idList IsNot Nothing Then
    For Each i As Integer In idList
      Dim record = source.Find(i)
      collection.Add(record)
    Next
  End If
End Sub
```